# git mv fails with error "fatal: source directory is empty"

Tags: git, git-bash

This is my current directory.

```
SI
└── SI_Code
    ├── src
    └── inc
```

With c files inside the src directory and h files inside the Inc directory.
All the files inside the folders are listed in git.

I want to rename the `SI_Code` directory to be `Libs`.

I'm trying to run

```
git mv SI_Code/ Libs/
```

And get the following error

```
fatal: source directory is empty, source=SI/SI_Program/SI_Code, destination=SI/SI_Program/Libs/SI_Code
```

I'm using Win10 and running the command in git bash.

Why am I getting the error?
Also, from the error message, it seems like `git mv` is trying to move the `SI_Code` directory inside the `libs` directory instead of renaming it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where the Git root folder is, but a more robust approach is to rename the folder in a simple CMD or directly through the Windows file explorer.

Then do a `git add .` then `git status`. Git will detect the move.
You can commit: `git commit -m "rename SI_Code/ to Libs"`

(Unless the `.git/` subfolder is under `SI_Code`, in which case there is not add/commit to do: the root folder name itself is not managed by Git)

Comment: I still didn't understand what causes the issue with the `git mv`.
Thanks for the help anyway I took your advice

Comment: @NoamYulzari The question remains: where is your `.git/` subfolder? Was it directly une `SI_Code`?

Comment: My .git subfolders is 2 directories above the directory tree added to the question.

Comment: @NoamYulzari OK, so the git mv should still have worked indeed. But using an OS `move` command is simpler: Git will figure it out after the system move.

Comment: Shows as add/delete not actual move.

Comment: @DavidV.Corbin Strange, it should detect the move, unless the content has also change. Please describe your scenario in a separate question, with OS and Git version.

Comment: @VonC - Things get complicated when there are multiple parts of the directory tree with IDENTICAL content. Apparently, this confuses the SHA matching aspects. - Windows, latest stable as of 72 hours ago. Renamed the directory in place (git mv), then moved the *unique* directory tree (file system, git add .) then did a git mv back to original name....

Comment: @DavidV.Corbin Interesting. Again, that would warrant to be described in a question on its own (and/or to be mentioned in https://public-inbox.org/git/)